# How to split a crypt_LUKS partition in half with LVM?

Tags: partition, lvm

I currently have this structure:

```
NAME                      FSTYPE
sdb                       iso9660
└─sdb1                    crypto_LUKS
  └─sdb1-map              ext4
```

And want to get

```
# lsblk -o name,fstype /dev/sdb

NAME                      FSTYPE
sdb                       iso9660
└─sdb1                    crypto_LUKS
  └─sdb1_map              LVM2_member
      └─lvm1              lvm
      └─lvm2              lvm
```

**What are the precise commands to turn the first configuration into the second?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precise commands are

```
pvcreate /dev/mapper/sdb1-map
vgcreate -s 10M mygroup /dev/mapper/sdb1-map 
lvcreate -L 100M -n lvm1 mygroup
lvcreate -L 100M -n lvm2 mygroup
```

where

- 10M is the extend size (PE size)

---

PS: to mount the partition, run `cryptsetup luksOpen [...]` and then `vgchange -a y` to open the lvm tree.